# Why "Error: Could not find or load main class addstudent.AddStudent" is showing

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am developing a project using NetBeans IDE. I am new to javafx. I created a class "AddStudent" in a package named "addstudent". When I ran the class, I got "Error: Could not find or load main class addstudent.AddStudent". Why this error is showing ? How can it solved ?

Comment: Do you think _all_ the code you posted is relevant? If not, why did you post it? If yes, why so? Please put some effort into writing your question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Is there no need to post the entire code ?

Comment: Why would you think so? Have you researched the error message you got? That should always be the first step. Post only relevant information.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for your notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running your code and it works fine. What I did

1. Created New -> JavaFx Main Class -> AdStudent -> Copy/Pasted your code
2. Right click on Project -> Properties -> Run -> <kbd>Browse</kbd> Application Class -> Select class `addstudent.AddStudent`
3. Clean and Build
4. Run Project

I have a feeling the first 2 are fine for you. You may just need to Clean and Build.

Comment: Yes. It worked now. Thanks. Why don't it worked when I ran it directly by pressing Shift+F6 ?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error while running my javaFx program.

And now I got the answer about how to fix it.

- Create your javaFx project on netBeans
- New Project-> JavaFx
- Application-> Finish

When you do this, you'll see a class with the same name as the name of the project.

When you try to run that file you'll get this error:

```
Error: Could not load or Find main class classname
```

to fix this error, simply rightclick on your project and click run.

Your project runs and you'll see something like, "say hello world". After that it will work fine.

One more thing, when you try to run your project with webstart on netBeans  it will not work!

And it is possible to get an error like

```
Error : javaFxApplication.jar could not Be deleted.
```

to fix this open your task manager and go to Background Process look for Java() Binary file 32 bit, just end that task and you're back.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was the **project path had some special** (russian) **chars**, like

```
C:\Dev\Папка\MyApp\
```

Once moved to another folder, it worked:

```
C:\Dev\Good one\MyApp\
```

Also:

- these characters are OK: ``` äöü!@#$%^&_+-``~_', ```
- these are not: `№;`