# Javapackager: Cannot find or load main class

Tags: java

I have created a `JavaFX` project and am able to run it with the command

`java -classpath [very-long-list-of-class-paths] danIDE.Main`

However, when I try to use `javapackager` to create a jar out of it and run with `java -jar out.jar`, the prompt says `Error: Could not find or load main class danIDE.Main`

The command I used to create the jar is

`javapackager -createjar -v -classpath [very-long-list-of-class-paths] -srcdir src -outfile out -appclass danIDE.Main`

I have googled for a long time on this problem and I still couldn't find the solution. Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks a lot!

---

Edit: 
Here is the project structure.

[image: Project Structure]

and here is the exploded jar.

[image]

New exploded jar as @Garry requested:

[image]

Comment: it says `Error: Unable to access jarfile out`. The `out.jar` is in the current directory @rakeb.void

Comment: I see, I'm trying to reproduce your error.

Comment: Possibly you are missing the classpath for `danIDE.Main`

Comment: @Arvind should I put the path to `danIDE` or the path to the parent of it in there?

Comment: @Arvind I tried both and neither worked :`(

Comment: Extract your `.jar` file using WinRAR or similar utility. Open the file `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` in any text editor. Find the value of the property `JavaFX-Application-Class:`. What is it?

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla I couldn't find `JavaFX-Application-Class` in the `MANIFEST.MF` file. I can see that `Main-Class` is `danIDE.Main`

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793628/why-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-addstudent-addstudent-is-showing

Comment: @GRC Thanks but I'm trying to run the jar outside an IDE.

Comment: Why does the exploded jar contain .java files? Shouldn't they be compiled .class files?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution, I also have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using IntelliJ IDEA I suggest you let IDEA create your JAR file for you.

First, open up the module settings window:

[image]

Then, add a new artifact:

[image]

Select *JAR* *From modules with dependencies*:

[image]

Select your main class in the window and decide if you want to repackage all classes from your dependency JARs in your JAR (*extract to target JAR* option) or if you want to distribute them alongside your JAR (*copy to the output directory and link via manifest* option):

[image]

If you want to build it whenever you build the project (probably a good idea), click the checkbox for that:

[image]

When you next *Make* the project, the JAR will show up under *out/artifacts*:

[image]

If you didn't click the checkbox for building the JAR when you build the project you can build the JAR from the *Build Artifacts* option in the *Build* menu.

Comment: I tried your solution and when running the jar it gave me this error: `Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again`

Comment: What dependencies do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try using below command? Make sure to update 'classes' folder to the Base directory of the files to package.

As you said in question that you are able to run `danIDE.Main` so I assume all the required classes are available in dist folder.
So create a folder `out` in the project parallel to `dist`

```
javapackager -createjar -classpath [very-long-list-of-class-paths] -appclass danIDE.Main -srcdir dist -outdir out -outfile out.jar -v
```

Updated: as per the uploaded screenshot: point `-srcdir` to `dist`, now the generated jar `out.jar` will be placed in `out/out.jar`

Comment: I apologize that I forgot to include the -srcdir and -outfile parameters in the question. I have updated my question accordingly. I did put those parameters when building. I also tried your command again and it's still `Could not find or load main class danIDE.Main`

Comment: @TengyuLiu can you share screenshot of your project structure and exploded jar contents.

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshots. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @TengyuLiu .. thanks. Just curious to saw the screenshot of exploded jar, why it has Main.java instead of Main.class. You should be setting the srcdir to the folder where the classes are generated not the src folder.

Comment: @TengyuLiu .. I have updated the answer as per the screenshot uplaoded

Comment: OK, so how is exploded jar now looks like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84636/discussion-between-tengyu-liu-and-garry).

Comment: @TengyuLiu Were you able to run it, as you said danIDE.Main is in Dist.jar so you need to include the dist.jar in your long list of classpath as well.

Comment: I added dist.jar and also `./out/artifacts/DanIDEv3JavaFX_jar` which contains all the `.class` files, but it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: I think there might be tiny piece of info that is missing but cant figure out, sorry